# Javascript Create an element with the various attributes

Tags: javascript, class, createelement

Can you create an element without acting every time like that?

```
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.class = codebuttons;
button.value = Backup
```

For example

```
document.querySelector('.right.Sub').appendChild(document.createElement("button").setAttribute("class", "codebuttons"));
```

Comment: you give the question your self and answer it tooo...what is left for us..

Answer (score 2):

Your "for example" code is very different from your code on top, but both need to be fixed.

First your initial code. That'll work except that you need to use `.className` to set the class. And of course you need quotation marks to create the strings.

```
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.className = "codebuttons";
button.value = "Backup";
```

---

Second, your bottom code won't work because you're not appending an element. You're appending the return result of `.setAttribute()`, which is `undefined`.

You can however chain `.setAttribute()` to the end of `.appendChild()` since it returns the appended element.

```
document.querySelector('.right.Sub')
        .appendChild(document.createElement("button"))
        .setAttribute("class", "codebuttons");
```

---

There are however issues in older versions of IE with setting the `"class"` using `setAttribute()`. So instead, set the property as in the first example.

```
document.querySelector('.right.Sub')
        .appendChild(document.createElement("button"))
        .className = "codebuttons";
```

Comment: With this code, I've got only type but not value.
document.querySelector('.right.Sub')
        .appendChild(document.createElement("input"))
        .setAttribute("type", "button")
        .setAttribute("value", "Backup");

Comment: Sure, if you need to set multiple attributes/properties then you should save the new element to a variable and set them.